# Debugging Assembly (from binary file) in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, binary-bomb

I'm trying to get the answer for one of those binary bombs. This is for school so please just help point me in the correct direction, I believe I am close to solving the puzzle.

Here's the piece of assembly I'm stuck on:

```
0x080485e9 <+127>:   call   0x8048400 <strtol@plt>
0x080485ee <+132>:   cmp    %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)
0x080485f5 <+139>:   je     0x80485fc <main+146>
0x080485f7 <+141>:   call   0x8048540 <bomb>
0x080485fc <+146>:   add    $0x1,%ebx
```

So I need to avoid the method call for the bomb, or else it will explode! This means that the statement `cmp %eax,0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)` must set the zero flag and `%eax` must be equal to `0x80498d4(,%ebx,4)`.

`'%eax'` Ends up becoming the input from the first line of a file I'm reading into the program. I have verified this in gdb.

I ran a print statement in gdb to see what the value of the second argument in cmp was so I could then equate it with `%eax`.

I ran:

```
print (0x80498d4 + $ebx*4)
```

in gdb which resulted in `$1 = 134519000`.

So I then plugged in the above to my input so I could get:

```
(gdb) print $eax
$2 = 134519000
```

Now both cmp arguments seemingly have the same value according to gdp, but the `je` jump if equal flag is still not evaluating to true and the `<bomb>` function is still being called.

Any pointers and help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have `%ebx == 1` at that point in the program? You might want to actually `print *(0x80498d4 + $ebx*4)`, and thus compare the value in memory, rather than the address...

Comment: Ha! This solved it (the updated print statement)... I'm new to using gdb and I blanked on de-referencing the value in the address, thanks!